# show values on top of bars on each colmnin chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

I have tried a lot to show values on top of char but I couldn't do it please could you help me with this
i have also add plugins to show data.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="100" aria-label="Hello ARIA World" role="img"></canvas>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  console.log({{sales_performance|safe}})
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Sales',
        data: [1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 10, 11, 16],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          display: false, // Hide the y-axis label
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: 'black', // Set the color of the data labels
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          },
          formatter: function(value, context) {
            return value; // Display the value on the bars
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });



</script>
```

I want to show values on top of each bar column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake that the *chartjs-plugin-datalabels* not working due to the library is not registered. You must [register the library](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) as stated in the documentation stated.

To position the data label on top of the bar chart, you need to add the `datalabels` property in each object of the `dataLabels` array. You may read the [Positioning](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#positioning) for the configuration.

```js
datasets: [
  {
    ...
    datalabels: {
      align: 'top',
      anchor: 'end',
    },
  }
]
```

Complete code:

```
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'July',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec',
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Sales',
          data: [1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 10, 11, 16],
          borderWidth: 1,
          datalabels: {
            align: 'top',
            anchor: 'end',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          display: false, // Hide the y-axis label
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: 'black', // Set the color of the data labels
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
          },
          formatter: function (value, context) {
            return value; // Display the value on the bars
          },
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  });
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-s3e4an?file=index.html)